# Determine the area of the region bounded by the graph of $f(x)$ and the lines$ x=0$, $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, area

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in[0,1]\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}\\1&x=\frac{1}{2} \end{cases}$. Determine the area of the region bounded by the graph of $f(x)$ and the lines $x=0$, $x=1$ and $y=0$.

Actually the area of the region bounded by some lines and curves is quite easy to see but for this one, I couldn't see where is that region.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: There was a typo. I've fixed the problem

Comment: $f$ is almost everywhere zero on $[0,1]$ so the integral should evaluate to zero as well, right? I am unsure how to handle this situation using Riemann-Integration though.

Comment: You are simply integrating for area of $f(x)$ above the y axis ($y=0$ bound) in the range $[0,1]$ ($x=0$ and $x=1$ bounds). To visualize, the area you want is the line segment under $(x,y)=(1/2,1)$ down to $(1/2,0)$, which is $0$. (That is, the area under $f=0$ in $[0,1/2)$ plus area under $f=0$ in $(1/2,1]$, which is $0+0$.)

Answer (score 1):

To visualize the region just draw the graph of $f$. Then it is clear that the region has zero area, since $f$ is different from zero just at a single point ($x=\frac{1}{2}$).

If you want to show it using integrals, then the area of the region is 
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx + \int_{1/2}^{1} f(x)dx = 0+0 = 0
$$